# Thymeleaf img not calling spring controler

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.+")
    compile("org.webjars:bootstrap:3.0.3")
    compile("org.webjars:jquery:2.0.3-1")
    compile("org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:2.0.7.RELEASE")  
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test:4.0.0.RELEASE")
    compile("org.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-spring4")
    compile("nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4")
    compile("javax.mail:mail:1.4.5")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-context-support:3.2.2.RELEASE")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2")
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

I have defined a method in my controller:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mainMenu/companyOfficeMainMenu/imagetest/{server_image_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public byte[] testphoto(@PathVariable("server_image_id") Long server_image_id) throws IOException {



        Image notUpdatedImage = mobileManagment.getImage(server_image_id);

        String locationRoot =  env.getProperty("location.sever.root");
        String locationOfCompanyData =  env.getProperty("location.compay.data");
        String locationOfImage =  env.getProperty("location.compay.media.images");


        String storeImageName = 
                locationOfCompanyData 
                + File.separator
                + locationOfImage 
                + File.separator
                + notUpdatedImage.getCompany_id() 
                + File.separator +
                + notUpdatedImage.getServer_questionnaire_attempt_key()
                + File.separator 
                + notUpdatedImage.getImage_name();      
        File uploadedFile = new File(locationRoot, storeImageName);             
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());


        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    }
```

And in Thymeleaf, I try to call it:

```
<img th:src="@{/mainMenu/companyOfficeMainMenu/imagetest/${object.getServer_image_id()}}" />
```

I have a break point in the method in the controller but it's not being called.

Here is also another method that does not get called:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/mainMenu/companyOfficeMainMenu/image/{server_image_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getImage(@PathVariable("server_image_id") Long server_image_id) throws IOException {

        Image notUpdatedImage = mobileManagment.getImage(server_image_id);

        String locationRoot =  env.getProperty("location.sever.root");
        String locationOfCompanyData =  env.getProperty("location.compay.data");
        String locationOfImage =  env.getProperty("location.compay.media.images");


        String storeImageName = 
                locationOfCompanyData 
                + File.separator
                + locationOfImage 
                + File.separator
                + notUpdatedImage.getCompany_id() 
                + File.separator +
                + notUpdatedImage.getServer_questionnaire_attempt_key()
                + File.separator 
                + notUpdatedImage.getImage_name();      
        File uploadedFile = new File(locationRoot, storeImageName);             
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());


        byte[] imageContent = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(imageContent, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mainMenu/companyOfficeMainMenu/imagetest/{server_image_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public byte[] testphoto(@PathVariable("server_image_id") Long server_image_id) throws IOException {



        Image notUpdatedImage = mobileManagment.getImage(server_image_id);

        String locationRoot =  env.getProperty("location.sever.root");
        String locationOfCompanyData =  env.getProperty("location.compay.data");
        String locationOfImage =  env.getProperty("location.compay.media.images");


        String storeImageName = 
                locationOfCompanyData 
                + File.separator
                + locationOfImage 
                + File.separator
                + notUpdatedImage.getCompany_id() 
                + File.separator +
                + notUpdatedImage.getServer_questionnaire_attempt_key()
                + File.separator 
                + notUpdatedImage.getImage_name();      
        File uploadedFile = new File(locationRoot, storeImageName);             
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());


        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    }
```

When I press f12 on the screen I can see the output of the image tag:

```
<img src="/mainMenu/companyOfficeMainMenu/image/${object.getServer_image_id()}">
```

That does not look right.

When I output I get 27 (which is correct)

```
<p th:text="${object.getServer_image_id()}"></p>
```

Comment: When you get the page output in your browser, press F12 and see what's going on with the `src` attribute of your `img` tag. You probably are getting an error while rendering the page or having the tag pointed to somewhere else.

Comment: could you show the code of `object.getServer_image_ids()`?

Comment: Hey, I've added your requests to the bottom of the post. Ken, there was a typo, I've changed the method to getServer_image_id() instead of getServer_image_ids(), but it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the [Thymeleaf Link URL](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) syntax correctly. You need to specify a parameter in braces (similar to the @RequestMapping) eg. `{server_image_id}`. Then you specify the value to replace it with afterwards between parenthesis `(server_image_id=${object.getServer_image_id()})`.

All together:

```
<img th:src="@{/mainMenu/companyOfficeMainMenu/imagetest/{server_image_id}(server_image_id=${object.getServer_image_id()})}" />
```